# How to handle delayed start of the application using process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have an app that is started in a separate process. Process remain alive until app discovers the problem and then exits.

How to handle the situation where process needs to report if application was started successfully or not ? Few approaches that I can think of,

1. wait for some time and check if process is still alive.
2. check the process status after some time. - this approach is not adequate for my use case.

I am sure there are more elegant solutions to this problem.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, ProcessError
import time 
from flask import Flask

def start_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
       return 'Hello World'
    app.run()  
    # ----> After few milliseconds (not known), there is an exception (port in use, run time exception) and process will exit at that time. 

p = Process(target=start_app)
p.start()
p.is_alive() # ----> True
time.sleep(5) 
p.is_alive() # ----> False or still True
```

If I sleep, there is no way, I can be sure that the process is not going to exit in next millisecond or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It somewhat depends on what you want to do in the main process after the child process has been started. The simplest solution is probably a loop: `while p.is_alive(): time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: I could do that but this results in false positive. When I start a process, it is alive when i check but after let's say few seconds, i may die. thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Please think again about my comment. I proposed to loop over `p.is_alive`. This is not going to exit until `p.is_alive` is false.

Comment: Ok I hear you. This could be one option. To give more context (that you asked in first comment), I receive an API call to start a app on some port and return or wait until app is alive and return. If i return without makings sure app indeed ran successfully, caller of the API call may get false information. I just wanted to avoid putting fix sleep value so was asking for some options. Appreciate your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Process.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join), which will block until the process `p` terminates, this way the waiting time will never be greater than what the process needs to finish.

You can also use it with a timeout so it will block until `p` terminates *or* the timeout is reached:

```py
try:
    p.join(10)
except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    logging.info("The process lasted more than 10 seconds")
```

Comment: Thank Terseus. Appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Terseus, I checked the multiprocessing documentation and nowhere it's mentioned that the join with timeout will raise TimeoutError. I also tried and does not seem to work.

Comment: @KetanPatel It's in the `multiprocessing.TimeoutError` description: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.TimeoutError

Comment: I agree that there is a ```multiprocessing.TimeoutError``` but it does not work with join. I have tried and does not work with me at least.